# Migrate repo from Github to a specific Gitlab group

Tags: github, gitlab

I want to migrate a repository from Github to my Gitlab group but it seems like there's no feature to do it. The import feature works but it imports to my personal Gitlab account, not a Gitlab group. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import feature does let you import projects into groups, but you must have permission to create repositories in that group. Navigate to the group, then click "create repo" then choose import. The dialog should also ask what namespace you want to import to; make sure to change it to the correct group.

You can also just push directly to a namespace and the project doesn't have to exist yet:

```sh
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.com/mygroup/my-new-project.git
git push -u origin --all
```

This will create the project for you.